# 500 - Internal Server Error on added php version on IIS 7 Win2008 R2

Tags: php, windows, iis, fastcgi, moodle

Newly added php version doesn't work on a Windows 2008 box with IIS 7.5 and FastCGI. Any php file will throw a 500 Internal Server Error. Once I switch php to current version via PHP Manager. Everything works fine. The application is Moodle but it will throw the same error on even a blank php file that I wrote for testing purpose.  The Check phpinfo() in PHP Manager will throw the same ISE 500.

The following attempts all failed.
1. Manually installed php into folder, create Handler mapping, create FastCGI settings, latest VC redistribute (both x64 and x86).
2. Delete all instances of the new php. Re-install it via WebPI. Verified handler mapps and FastCGI setting.

I can switch PHP via PHP Manager for my Moodle instances. Yes I have more than one instances. The ones with old php work and the ones with new php version will not work. Since Check phpinfo() in PHP Manager throws error, I ruled out my Moodle settings in troubleshooting. I turned on error logging in php.ini. The error log file remains blank.

I have read many threads and have checked my IIS settings about a million times in the last 2 days. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: check the iis and system error logs for details abou the 500

Comment: Events log contains a few errors like this. 
Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 7.5.7601.17514, time stamp: 0x4ce7afa2
Faulting module name: iisfcgi.dll, version: 7.5.7601.17514, time stamp: 0x4ce7c6cb
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00000000000079f2
Faulting process id: 0xe00
Faulting application start time: 0x01d05c1814689f91
Faulting application path: c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\iisfcgi.dll
Report Id: 1a9fa25e-c80e-11e4-a732-00505682219c